# Problems with Lists and Dictionaries

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with a Dictionary of Lists for both the Key and Value.

My dictionary is set up as this

```
Dictionary<List<string>,List<double>> f = new Dictionary<List<string>,List<double>>();
```

(it's like this for a very specific reason).

My problem is how to get the two lists out into their own lists. I have tried the following

```
List<string> s = new List<string>(f.Keys);
List<string> s = f.Select(kvp=>kvp.Keys).ToList()
List<string> s = f.Select(kvp=>kvp.Keys);
List<string> s = f.Keys;
```

as well as a variant using IEnumerable. No matter what I do, I can't seem to retrieve the Keys (or using f.Values, the values).

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: Yikes. I'm not sure what you're trying to do... but I'm fairly sure there's gotta be a better way.

Comment: Are you sure something like a `Tuple<List<string>, List<double>>` wouldn't be a better solution?

Comment: Are you sure that what you really want isn't a `List<Dictionary<string, double>>`?  Even then, you may want to consider encapsulating the inner Dictionary into a more descriptive named class like `ProcessSettings` rather than nesting collections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of strings seems like a VERY odd key for a dictionary, and will have complexities of its own, but you seem confident that it's correct, so I'll focus on your actual question.

Since `Keys` is a *collection* of key values, each of which is a `List<string>`, any of these should work:

```
List<List<string>> s = f.Select(kvp=>kvp.Key).ToList();
List<List<string>> s = f.Keys.ToList();
```

If you want ALL strings as a single list (essentially joining all of the lists together), you can use:

```
List<string> s2 = f.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
```

The `SelectMany` essentially selects each item from the collection within each key across the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Lol This is probably the funniest thing I've seen in a while.

Alright. In c# there is a structure called `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. You can then iterate through the entire dataset with foreach and get access to what you want.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<<List<string>,List<double>> item in f) {
    List<string> key = item.key;
    List<double> value = item.value;
}
```

Comment: You should watch more funny things.

Comment: This is an ideal candidate for the `var` keyword.

Comment: Yea, I'm not the biggest fan of `var`. I like to know what my objects are. Kind of leftovers from C++.

Comment: @ZorleQ - here is how we settled this - var is fine inline when you can see the type on the line - but should not be used on method / property returns where you have to go somewhere else to figure out the type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 key,meaning 1 list of strings:

```
List<string> newf = f.Keys.ElementAt(0);
```

If you have more place another index.
Or check if the list as some item so that would be the list to retrieve:

```
List<string> newf = f.Keys.Single(k => k.Contains("SomeString"));
//this must exist or it will throw exception.
```

Get a key by checking if the corresponding values sum is above(or less,or equal...)

```
var newf1 = f.Where(k => k.Value.Sum() > 10).Select(v => v.Key);
```